# Wordpress plugin add page frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin for wordpress. This plugin has to have an admin section for plugin set up but also has to have a custom front end page with forms.

I'm new into the wordpress plugin development world but I have not found specific information for this task.

Is there a way to add pages to front end from a plugin or is necessary to manually edit the current template and add the page?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to add custom content on a front-end page when you create your plugin: http://blog.frontendfactory.com/how-to-create-front-end-page-from-your-wordpress-plugin/

```
function elegance_referal_init()
{
    if(is_page('share')){   
        $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        include($dir."frontend-form.php");
        die();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'elegance_referal_init' );
```

Comment: I followed the example code and it works except the header/footer do not load - Why? http://pocket.consulting/bg-core

Comment: I know this is old, but for anyone looking at it in the future, @G-J you would need to call get_header() and get_footer() on your included page to get the header and footer to show.  Also this method requires you to add a page in the database. Use the action 'pre_get_posts' with the global $wp variable and check its request to add a page without adding it to the database. (Code in separate answer)

Comment: @G-J its because of die();

Answer (score 1):

To add a page to Wordpress that runs custom code without adding the page as a post or page in the database, try this in your plugin file.

```
add_action ('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
   
    global $wp;
    if ($wp->request == 'pageurl'){   
        $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        include $dir . "your_file.php";
        die();
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you looking for this for the admin settings page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page

Fot the front end, i would recommend to create a page with a template https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Comment: second link removed: That page can’t be found. is there any other article there?